# Why does php 016 divided by 2 answering 7?

Tags: php

I am trying to divide 016 by 2 an php answer 7.
Why does php 016 divided by 2 answering 7?
for example,

```
<?php 
$i=016;
echo $i/2;
?>
```

output is 7 
why?

Comment: Because `0` in the begining indicates octal base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP interprets an integer with a leading 0 as an octal (base 8) number. `016` base 8 is `14` base 10.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).
>
> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> **To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).** To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

If you actually need to print the `0`, you are better off doing one of two things:

1. Use regular integers, padding with zero only at display time. I recommend this option.
2. Pass around strings, instead of integers. This will work well only if you don't need to do math with the strings.

Comment: Thanks for valuable response.